# How to crop image after selecting it from gallery using ActivityResultLauncher<> in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I crop image to 1:1 after selecting it from gallery using `ActivityResultLauncher<>`. Is there any way to do it without using libraries (because I am already using a lot of libraries in my project). Below is my code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(result).into(shapeableImageView);
                }
            }
        });

private void openImagePicker() {
    activityResultLauncher.launch("image/*");
}
```

Update:

I am at api: 16 and I have tried to use some cropping libraries but some are at api: 19 and other one (Android Image Cropper) is not working. I have no idea what code I use to crop image with `ActivityResultLauncher<>` (without libraries). I am new to android development and please tell me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: "it is done by using Intent everywhere on internet" -- there are many [image cropping libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), easily discovered by using [the Internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=android+image+cropping+library&ia=web).

Comment: I am sorry I meant without using external libraries. I have changed question now.

Comment: There is no option without external libraries, except for you to write your own image-cropping code from scratch. You can use those libraries for inspiration for how to do that.

Comment: Ok thanks I will use libraries then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github Library it will help you.

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker).

```
  ImagePicker.Companion.with(this)
                .crop()                    //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
                .compress(1024)            //Final image size will be less than 1 MB(Optional)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start();//Final image resolution will be less than 1080 x 1080(Optional)
```

On Activity Result.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {
                selectedFileURI = data.getData();

                if (selectedFileURI != null && !Objects.requireNonNull(selectedFileURI.getPath()).isEmpty()) {

                    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    civUser.setImageURI(selectedFileURI);
                    Glide.with(context).load(selectedFileURI).into(civUser);
                    btnUploadDp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    Functions.showSnackBar(context, "Cannot Get this Image");

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It will not work on API: 16

Comment: No from API 19 to upword.