# Issue swapping image

Tags: java, android, gallery

I have a ProfileActivity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    final ImageView exampleImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.exampleImageView);
    exampleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [TODO] Implement application behavior when the user clicks the profile picture
            //Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, GalleryActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

and I have a second activity called 'GalleryActivity'. the concept is to let the user choose a image from the gallery and then use it to replace the original Profile image.

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
    Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
                    imageUri = data.getData();
                    imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
            }
    }
```

}

however, when I click on a image of the gallery, instead of taking it as new profile image, it take me back to the original image.
what is happening and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Github Library it will help you.

Here is the [Link](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker).

```
ImagePicker.Companion.with(this)
                .crop()                    //Crop image(Optional), Check Customization for more option
                .compress(1024)            //Final image size will be less than 1 MB(Optional)
                .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
                .start();//Final image resolution will be less than 1080 x 1080(Optional)
```

On Activity Result.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {
                selectedFileURI = data.getData();

                if (selectedFileURI != null && !Objects.requireNonNull(selectedFileURI.getPath()).isEmpty()) {

                    btnUpdate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    civUser.setImageURI(selectedFileURI);
                    Glide.with(context).load(selectedFileURI).into(civUser);
                    btnUploadDp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {

                    Functions.showSnackBar(context, "Cannot Get this Image");

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Refernce [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69358590/13560223).